# Motion of a particle defined via Lebesgue integral

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Suppose $x_0 =0$. A particle moves as follows:

$$x_t = \int_0^t a(s) ds$$

where $a: \mathbb{R}_+ \to \{-1,0,1\}$ is a measurable function.

Suppose, I have that $a_s = 1$ if $x_s = 0$. I want to write the following, seemingly intuitive, claim.

**Claim:** $x_s \ge 0$ for all $s \ge 0$.

The logic is obvious. The moment the particle hits $0$, it's pushed to the right. But I just don't have a way to argue this formally. How can I proceed?

Thanks.

Comment: but that can't be true, isn't it? Just take $a(0)=1$ and $a(s)=-1$ for any other $s$. We clearly have $x(s)\le 0$ here and $a$ is measurable.

Comment: @BigbearZzz But what you have is different from what I listed. $a(0)=1$ is not the same as $a(s) = 1$ whenever $x(s)=0$.

Comment: @AlexR., as I said intuitively that seems to be the case. $a_s = 1$ whenever $x_s = 0$ means that the instantaneous velocity of the particle at $0$ is $1$ and its direction is $+$.